# PHP Unset parent if not found in an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, parent-child

I'm having an issue unsetting my parent if I do not find my needle in my child, for some reason I just cannot get this to work no matter how many different ways I try it, could someone possibly point me in the right direction? This is being thrown at a multidimensional array with a floor depth of about 4. Here's the code and an example of what a slice of the array might look like. In this case only Array[3] should remain, Array's [1-2] should be removed.

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    197015 => 
    array (
      345415 => 
      array (
        'options' => 
        array (
          'Name on Credential' => '',
          'Ordination Month' => '',
          'Ordination Day' => '',
          'Ordination Year' => '',
          'Badge Choice?' => '',
        ),
        'comments' => 
        array (
          213354 => '',
        ),
        'products_name' => '',
        'products_quantity' => '',
        'delivery_country' => '',
        'customers_name' => '',
        'delivery_name' => '',
        'delivery_street_address' => '',
        'delivery_city' => '',
        'delivery_postcode' => '',
        'delivery_state' => '',
        'customers_telephone' => '',
      ),
    ),
  ),

  2 => 
  array (
    197014 => 
    array (
      345414 => 
      array (
        'options' => 
        array (
          'Name on Credential' => '',
          'Ordination Month' => '',
          'Ordination Day' => '',
          'Ordination Year' => '',
          'Badge Choice?' => '',
        ),
        'comments' => 
        array (
          213353 => '',
        ),
        'products_name' => '',
        'products_quantity' => '',
        'delivery_country' => '',
        'customers_name' => '',
        'delivery_name' => '',
        'delivery_street_address' => '',
        'delivery_city' => '',
        'delivery_postcode' => '',
        'delivery_state' => '',
        'customers_telephone' => '',
      ),
    ),
  ),

  3 => 
  array (
    197013 => 
    array (
      345412 => 
      array (
        'options' => 
        array (
          'Name on Credential' => '',
          'Ordination Month' => '',
          'Ordination Day' => '',
          'Ordination Year' => '',
        ),
        'comments' => 
        array (
          213352 => '',
        ),
        'products_name' => 'Jedi',
        'products_quantity' => '1',
        'delivery_country' => '',
        'customers_name' => '',
        'delivery_name' => '',
        'delivery_street_address' => '',
        'delivery_city' => '',
        'delivery_postcode' => '',
        'delivery_state' => '',
        'customers_telephone' => '',
      ),
      345413 => 
      array (
        'options' => 
        array (
          '' => '',
        ),
        'comments' => 
        array (
          213352 => '',
        ),
        'products_name' => '',
        'products_quantity' => '',
        'delivery_country' => '',
        'customers_name' => '',
        'delivery_name' => '',
        'delivery_street_address' => '',
        'delivery_city' => '',
        'delivery_postcode' => '',
        'delivery_state' => '',
        'customers_telephone' => '',
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Here's a sample of the last code I tried using without success, if you replace unset($k); with return false; it will return which secondary array the needle appears in.

```
    // array_search with recursive searching, optional partial matches and optional search by key
    function array_find_r($needle, &$haystack, $partial_matches = false, $search_keys = false) {
        if(!is_array($haystack)) return false;
        foreach($haystack as $key=>&$value) {
            $what = ($search_keys) ? $key : $value;
            if($needle===$what) return $key;
            else if($partial_matches && @strpos($what, $needle)!==false) return $key;
            else if(is_array($value) && array_find_r($needle, $value, $partial_matches, $search_keys)!==false) return $key;
        }
        unset($k);
    }

$tty = array();
foreach($datas as &$k) {
    $tty[] = array_find_r('Jedi', &$k, true, false);
}

$tty=array_filter($tty); rsort($tty);


echo '<pre>'; var_export($datas); echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not push the data you do need into a new array and unset the whole old array?